# encoding WAV data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am generating WAV data using JavaScript, and I'm able to generate the data and store it in a variable `waveFileOutput`, then send it to an embedded player by setting the source to following dataURI I set up:

> var dataURI = "data:audio/wav;base64," + escape(btoa(waveFileOutput));

I'm also able to get the file to (sort of) "save" by opening a window using the same data after encoding it and saving the window as a file. The problem is that the data is not properly encoded as a WAV file in the new window, even though the embedded play is fine with the encoding. I need to figure out the correct way to encode it. Here are a couple of things I've tried (but neither works):

> Try #1: window.open("data:application/octet-stream," +
>   encodeURIComponent(waveFileOutput));
>
> Try #2: window.open("data:application/octet-stream," +
>   escape(btoa(waveFileOutput)));

I can post the whole (working) file if that helps, but seemed like it might be a waste of space.

Suggestions for how to get the data encoded properly when "saving" it using this approach?

Comment: Why do you want to open it in a new window?

Comment: I want to "save" the file, and opening it in a new window just gives the user the opportunity to do that. Getting it to play is fine, but the ultimate goal is to get it to save on disk. I know there are different approaches to this, but this was the most straight-forward I could find. And it works, in the sense that the data plays as a sound in the player, and the files gets saved to disk. However, the encoding in the saved file is wrong.

Comment: I suspect the escape or encodeURIComponent are corrupting it. did you try removing them?

Comment: Yes, I also tried just sending data stored in 'waveFileOutput' directly, and it saved and even had a header that looked somewhat reasonable, but the binary data did not look the same as data for the same wave form generated by another program, and I couldn't get any software to play the file, so that format is still not properly encoded.